# How to determine the order of an n by n matrix in a group

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I've been using this fast pseudo random number generator

```
// Initialize seed on any non-zero value
unsigned long long *seed;

unsigned long long
xorshift_get_internal ()
{
    seed ^= seed << 1;
    seed ^= seed >> 7;
    seed ^= seed << 9;
    return seed;
}
```

for some time now.  It's based on the following paper from George Marsaglia: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v08/i14/paper , with the three values for the shifts taken from the table towards the top of page $3$.

What I would like to do is try and understand the theory behind how this works, in particular the first two paragraphs of Section 3.

If I read it correctly, the matrix $L$ that he mentions would have the following form as a $4$ by $4$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

and increasing the power "pushes" the diagonal of 1's further away from the "prime" diagonal.

-- Edit --

Thanks to Augustin I now know that the order of the matrix in this context is the smallest power p > 1 such that for a matrix m $m^p = I$ where I is the identity.  What I do not see is a fast way to determine this short of a brute force multiply, which is not feasible in a reasonable length of time when we're talking orders in the range $2^{64} - 1$ .

Comment: Page 4 he's talking about the order of a matrix in a group. So it would be the smallest integer $p$ such that $M^p=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: You can quickly calculate the order of a degree $n$ matrix over the finite field of order $q$ provided that you can factorize $q^k-1$ for $k \le n$: See http://www.dr-celler.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/order.ps.gz In this case $q=2$ (it is about binary matrices) and I think factorizations of $2^k-1$ have been computed for large $k$.